# How to return an absolute path if i have only a relative path in NestJS?

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I have a NestJS project with a typeORM driver (MySQL). When a user uploads a photo then the server saves file in public directory and saves a relative path in DB: /public/user22.png

When a user sends a request for getting info about their profile, the server should return an absolute path.
Also a user can get a list of users.

I can edit the returning object for the user profile. But i don't want to use cycle for editing the list of users. Are there any optimal algorithms to solve the issue?

Comment: What do you mean by saying `I don't want to use cycle` ?

Comment: @HugoSohm I mean 
const _news = this.newsRepo.find({});

const newsCorrectImageUrl = _news.map((news) = ({ 
...news,
photo: "https://example.com/" + news.photo, // <---- this
}))

Comment: I understand, I'll write you an answer to explain you the two solutions

Answer (score 0):

You have two solutions to transform your relative path to an absolute path.

First option is to append every image used in your front-end based on an environment variable called `apiBaseUrl` for example.

```js
const users = await axios.get('/users');

<img src={`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASEURL}/${users.image}`}/>
```

It will start to be unoptimized if you'r using this many times of course.

**Second option** is to create modify  before returning your result to modify your `photo` value with an environment variable called `baseUrl` for example.

```js
const result: exampleEntity = this.exampleRepository.find();

const newExample: exampleEntity = this.exampleRepository.create({
      ...result,
      photo: this.configService.baseUrl + result.photo,
    });

return entityExample;
```

If you don't handle environment variables for the moment, you can read the [configuration documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration)